# Is there a way to disable Genius updates in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to prevent iTunes from performing Genius updates each time it launches?

[image]

I don't use this feature, and the process seems to slow down the process of getting access to the store and to my connected iOS devices.

Comment: "... simply go to Store menu ..." Store menu? I can't find anything labeled "menu"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Apple iTunes page](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/userCollectionsLearnMore?sf=143441):

> To turn off Genius, select Turn Off Genius from the Store menu. Once
>   you turn off Genius, iTunes will no longer send information about your
>   iTunes library to Apple.

This [About.com page](http://ipod.about.com/od/advanceditunesuse/a/hide_genius_bar.htm) also notes:

> If you want to completely turn off the Genius features, not just hide
>   them, simply go to the Store menu in iTunes and choose "Turn off
>   Genius."

I've confirmed that it can be turned off in the iTunes instance on my MBP.

Comment: But what about [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3907696) (also from the ToS): "You will not be able to disable Genius while using iTunes Match, so if you prefer that we do not collect and use information from your iTunes library in this manner, you should not use iTunes Match."

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, good point - the original question didn't mention iTunes Match. This answer would not apply in that case.

Comment: I hadn't noticed until I looked at that menu, but appears that Match got turned off somehow, and Genius was enabled instead (I don't recall doing that, and wouldn't have, so I'd be curious whether that's happened to others). With Genius off, and Match back on, the Genius update that I was concerned about doesn't happen anymore, so things work fine (and it looks like your answer still applies).